# Ubuntu Android Studio Gradle syn error: configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle

I've been working on an android development project for a few months now. My Windows and Mac machines were just not powerful enough so i've built a desktop and installed ubuntu 14.04

i've gone through all the setup steps and cloned the code i've been using from github and now android studio is giving me this gradle sync error. I've looked at similar questions but they don't seem relevant. This all works fine for me and my colleague on our other machines. I really need to get this running on my new machine.

Here is the error:

Gradle 'android-tablet' project refresh failed
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

completely stumped here.. anyone have any suggestion?#

it has to be some ubuntu environment/ android studio setting that i must have wrong

Comment: post your gradle file

Answer (score 1):

Inside the project, check the `build.gradle` file that's inside the app hierarchy (i.e., not the top-level `build.grade` file).  It probably has a `defaultConfig{}` block.  Make sure that `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` values match what you have downloaded via the SDK Manager for your new Ubuntu install.